# primeng paginator not working IE 11 when deployed on server

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, primeng

I have used pagination via p-table. In the image below, when user clicks on the very last page, the data in last page gets displayed but the page number is not updated in bottom right. This issue occurs in IE that too when deployed on server (works locally).
Below we can see the page number as 879 but in extreme right it does not show the correct page number
[image]

Expected behavior:
On click of last page, the specific page number should be displayed
If the current behavior is a bug or you can illustrate your feature request better with an example,

Environment:
IE 11

Angular version: 10.1.2

PrimeNG version: 10

<p-table #dt [columns]="cols"  [exportFilename]="" [value]="" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="load($event)"
[paginator]="true" [(first)]="0" [rows]="rowsPerPage" [totalRecords]="totalCount" [loading]="loading"
tableStyleClass="table table-hover table-striped">

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE 11? Could you please try to clear IE cache and try again? If it still doesn't work, please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. So that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: No Errors in console and I use private mode in IE

Comment: have you fixed it, i'm havine same issue when deployed in tomcat